# How to get Uri source for ConnectionSettingsType in windows phone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a windows phone app. I need to get Uri source to the ConnectionSettingsType.Wifi . But, it seems there is no way to do that. Kindly suggest me a way if possible

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [How to use the connection settings task for Windows Phone (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

There's no such thing as a URI available to 3rd party applications. You'll have to use the task to launch the settings page.